# Undefined method `name/each' for nil:NilClass whilst testing index view with associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have the association that 'one client has many books'.

Instead of the index view of books showing `client_id => 1`, I have edited it to show the client's name; it works, but the test says different.

I am trying to seed the test database with an example client and book, but I cannot seem to get it working.

Can you see where I am going wrong?

I think it has something to do with 'nil:NilClass'.

**spec/views/books/index.html.erb_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "books/index" do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:clients, [
      stub_model(Client,
        :name => "Name",
        :email => "Email Address",
      )
    ])
    assign(:books, [
      stub_model(Book,
        :title => "Title",
        :client_id => 1
      )
    ])
  end

  it "renders a list of books" do
    render
    # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat matchers
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "Title".to_s, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => 1.to_s, :count => 2
  end
end
```

**app/models/book.rb**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :client

  attr_accessible :title, :client_id

  validates :title, presence: true

end
```

**app/models/client.rb**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books

  attr_accessible :name, :email

  before_save { |user| user.email = email.downcase }

  validates :name,  presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }

  VALID_EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

end
```

**app/controllers/books_controller.rb** (snippet)

```
class BooksController < ApplicationController

  # GET /books
  # GET /books.json
  def index
    @books = Book.all

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @books }
    end
  end

end
```

**app/views/books/index.html.erb**

```
<h1>Listing books</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Title</th>
    <th>Client Name</th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
    <th></th>
  </tr>

<% @books.each do |book| %>
  <tr>
    <td><%= book.title %></td>
    <td><%= book.client.name %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Show', book %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_book_path(book) %></td>
    <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', book, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
</table>

<br />

<%= link_to 'New Book', new_book_path %>
```

**Test output**

```
  1) books/index renders a list of books
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/books/index.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_books_index_html_erb__##########_#####'
     # ./app/views/books/index.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_books_index_html_erb__##########_#####'
     # ./spec/views/books/index.html.erb_spec.rb:20:in `(root)'
```

---

## Using Factories

If instead I use FactoryGirl, I get a similar error "undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass".

**spec/views/books/index.html.erb_spec.rb**

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "books/index" do
  before do
    FactoryGirl.create(:book)
  end

  it "renders a list of books" do
    render
    # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat matchers
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => "Title".to_s, :count => 2
    assert_select "tr>td", :text => 1.to_s, :count => 2
  end
end
```

**Test output**

```
  1) books/index renders a list of books
     Failure/Error: render
     ActionView::Template::Error:
       undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/books/index.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_books_index_html_erb___##########_#####'
     # ./spec/views/books/index.html.erb_spec.rb:9:in `(root)'
```

Comment: Clearly the `@books` variable is empty. Can you add your controller code to your question, or atleast the index action of it, So I can see how   `@books` is instantiated?

Comment: Does your Book model have a belongs_to association with Client?

Comment: @Arjan I have added the controller code to my question.

Comment: @flpgr Yes it does - I have added the model code of Book and Client to my question.

Comment: Does your factory actually work? What happens if you go into console and try `FactoryGirl.create(:book)`?

Comment: Yea, and automatically creates a client to match.

Comment: Is it possible that due to the location of the spec file it bypasses the controller?

Comment: Am facing this same problem,how was it resolved please @Crimbo

Comment: @chrisgeeq It never was resolved in the end 

Comment: I just posted what worked for me @Crimbo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### First Error

```
undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/books/index.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_books_index_html_erb__##########_#####'
```

Which refers to line 15 of `app/views/books/index.html.erb`, is because there isn't an entry field called 'name'. So then the interpreter looks for a method of similar name, but can't find that; hence the 'undefined method' error. The reason why there isn't an entry with that field name is because the entry failed to save at the beginning of the test - the email provided "Email Address" isn't a valid email address. You will see there is a validator at line 11 of `app/models/client.rb`.

---

### Using Factories Error

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
     # ./app/views/books/index.html.erb:12:in `_app_views_books_index_html_erb___##########_#####'
```

Which refers to line 12 of `app/views/books/index.html.erb` is because only one entry of book is created at line 5 of `spec/views/books/index.html.erb_spec.rb`. There needs to be more than one for `.each` to be utilised, as @chrisgeeq points out.

Answer (score 1):

We had the same issue and realized the `` undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass ``  error message occurs probably because rspec is trying to call each on a single object,hence adding more books to the book model should resolve the error,here is an example

```
let(:books) { [Book.create!(title: "Stackoverflow for beginners"), 
  Book.create!(title:"hackeranks for intermediates")] }

before do
  assign(:book, books)
end
```

This worked for me !

Comment: But that's in reference to the FactoryGirl error right? Which I see is a difference error to rspec. The error is line 12 of 'index.html.erb' `<% @books.each do |book| %>` which relates to it being `books.each`.

I think, now looking at the properly, that the original error relates to line 15 of 'index.html.erb' `<td><%= book.client.name %></td>` is because rspec cannot find a client entry in the database and retrieve the client 'name' for the book. And the reason why is because it couldn't successfully create a client entry at the start because the email format was incorrect!

Comment: The email entry "Email Address" is not a valid email format!! It should be something like "mail@example.com". If you look at `client.rb` you will see that there is an email validator `validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }`. I guess I know more about understand errors now.